# Error sending html with mailR "can only read in bytes in a non-UTF-8 MBCS locale"

Tags: r, email, utf-8, r-markdown

The environment is windows 7 and Rstudio version 4.0.1
I want to send html created with Rmarkdown using mailR.
I am using the following code.

#### send.R

```
library(rmarkdown)
rmarkdown::render("example.Rmd")

library(mailR)

send.mail(from = "me@gmail.com",
          to = "me@gmail.com",
          subject = "R Markdown Report - rmarkdown",
          html = T,
          inline = T,
          body = "example.html",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "me", passwd = "password", ssl = T),
          authenticate = T,
          send = T)
```

#### example.Rmd

````
---
title: "Report for email"
output: 
  html_document: 
    self_contained: no
---

```{r}
summary(cars)  

\```
````

Using this code I get the following error

```
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(body, file.info(body)$size) :
  can only read in bytes in a non-UTF-8 MBCS locale
```

With this code

```
body = "example.html",
```

change

```
body = "text",
```

The transmission is successful
Is there a solution?
Thank you